# Laravel: How do I parse this json data in view blade?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

Currently this is my view

```
{{ $leads }}
```

And this is the output

```
{"error":false,"member":[{"id":"1","firstName":"first","lastName":"last","phoneNumber":"0987654321","email":"email@yahoo.com","owner":{
"id":"10","firstName":"first","lastName":"last"}}]}
```

I wanted to display something like this

```
Member ID: 1
Firstname: First
Lastname: Last
Phone: 0987654321

Owner ID: 10
Firstname: First 
Lastname: Last
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's pretty easy. 
First of all send to the view decoded variable (see [Laravel Views](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views)):

```
view('your-view')->with('leads', json_decode($leads, true));
```

Then just use common blade constructions (see [Laravel Templating)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates):

```
@foreach($leads['member'] as $member)
    Member ID: {{ $member['id'] }}
    Firstname: {{ $member['firstName'] }}
    Lastname: {{ $member['lastName'] }}
    Phone: {{ $member['phoneNumber'] }}

    Owner ID: {{ $member['owner']['id'] }}
    Firstname: {{ $member['owner']['firstName'] }} 
    Lastname: {{ $member['owner']['lastName'] }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 14):

For such case, you can do like this

```
@foreach (json_decode($leads->member) as $member)
     {{ $genre }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is awesome for me, because I want to use blade for some views and vue for others but don't want 2 different controller files (one returning json and the other for blade).  I can just return json data to both and it works.  That is awesome!

Answer (score 9):

Example if you have array format like this:

```
$member = [
    [ "firs_name" => "Monica",
      "last_name" => "Dev",
      "sex" => "F"
    ],
    [ "firs_name" => "Blake",
      "last_name" => "Devante",
      "sex" => "M"
    ],
    [ "firs_name" => "Johnny",
      "last_name" => "Merritt",
      "sex" => "M"
    ]
]
```

You can use `@json` Blade directive for Laravel 5.5 to 9.x

```
<script>
 var app = @json($member);
</script>
```

From Laravel `8.x` to latest version you can use `Illuminate\Support\Js::from` method directive.

```
<script>
var app = {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($member) }};
</script>
```

And for short with `Js` facade

```
<script>
var app = {{ Js::from($array) }};
</script>
```

Reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/blade

Comment: The (low quality, 7 year old) question is about parsing JSON data, not turning a PHP variable into JSON.

Comment: @miken32, Yes, It is old but it is still value until now. Yes, we are talking about parsing JSON data in Laravel view that all most array data or object in PHP and we still use Laravel until now and these Blade directive still value to using. So I wrote a bit more detail how to parsing JSON data in Laravel view for Javascript variables.

Answer (score 7):

The catch all for me is taking an object, encoding it, and then passing the string into a javascript `script` tag.  To do this you have to do some replacements.

First replace every `\` with a double slash `\\` and then every quote`"` with a `\"`.

```
$payload = json_encode($payload);
$payload = preg_replace("_\\\_", "\\\\\\", $payload);
$payload = preg_replace("/\"/", "\\\"", $payload);
return View::make('pages.javascript')
  ->with('payload', $payload)
```

Then in the blade template

```
@if(isset($payload))
<script>
  window.__payload = JSON.parse("{!!$payload!!}");
</script>
@endif
```

This basically allows you to take an object on the php side, and then have an object on the javascript side.

Comment: Killing flies with cannon shots

Answer (score 6):

You can use json decode then you get php array,and use that value as your own way

```
<?php 
$leads = json_decode($leads, true);
dd($leads);
```

Answer (score 3):

in controller just convert json data to object using json_decode php function like this

```
$member = json_decode($json_string); 

and pass to view in view

return view('page',compact('$member'))
```

in view blade

```
Member ID: {{$member->member[0]->id}}
Firstname: {{$member->member[0]->firstname}}
Lastname: {{$member->member[0]->lastname}}
Phone: {{$member->member[0]->phone}}

Owner ID: {{$member->owner[0]->id}}
Firstname: {{$member->owner[0]->firstname}}
Lastname: {{$member->owner[0]->lastname}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is coming from a model you can do:

**App\Http\Controller\SomeController**

```
public function index(MyModel $model)
{
    return view('index', [
        'data' => $model->all()->toJson(),
    ]);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@push('footer-scripts')
  <script>
    (function(global){
      var data = {!! $data !!};
      console.log(data);
      // [{..}]
    })(window);
  </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove **$** in to compact method ,
 return view('page',compact('member'))