# Displaying nested json in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have a nested json file

```
{
        "event_type": "INCOMING_BTC",
        "event_uid": "5515c5601f7b3",
        "datetime": "2015-03-27 21:02:37",
        "resources": [
            {
                "resource_type": "transaction",
                "resource": {
                    "id": 105062,
                    "datetime": "2015-03-27 21:02:23",
                    "description": "Money from Xapo Tip",
                    "order_type": "payment_received",
                    "from": {
                        "type": "btc_address",
                        "id": "1AqF787aPHgPRZ81kdQSeEwW46yjyrAaxR"
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "destination_type": "btc_address",
                        "destination_id": "1N65Bz88zKUDPKhUUsx8f9Qwsuo96Hqz7S",
                        "to_account": 1276
                    },
                    "generic_type": "credit",
                    "amount": "0.0000001",
                    "currency": "BTC",
                    "status": "completed",
                    "txConfidence": 1,
                    "rejection_reason": null,
                    "notes": null,
                    "base_currency": "USD",
                    "exchange_rate": null,
                    "exchange_amount": null
                }
            },
            {
                "resource_type": "address",
                "resource": {
                    "id": "1N65Bz88zKUDPKhUUsx8f9Qwsuo96Hqz7S",
                    "address": "1N65Bz88zKUDPKhUUsx8f9Qwsuo96Hqz7S",
                    "meta_data": null,
                    "label": null,
                    "total_received": "0.00000350",
                    "created_at": "2015-03-08 14:50:59",
                    "address_type": "multisig",
                    "id_account": "1276"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

And I have saved this file in public folder with name xapojson.txt

In my routes file I have done json_decode to decode this data to a variable 'transaction' and passed it to view

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    $transaction = json_decode(file_get_contents('xapojson.txt'));
    return view('transaction', compact('transaction'));
});
```

Now in transaction view I have to display the data from this nested json.
I have tried out lots of variation and searched on google and stackoverflow but nothing worked.
I found this somewhat helpful [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade). But it also do not get into more nesting.

In the view I have to display these datas:-

```
resources[0]->resource->from->type

resources[0]->resource->id

resources[0]->resource->from->id

resources[0]->resource->status

resources[0]->resource->amount

resources[0]->resource->currency

resources[0]->resource->to->destination_id

datetime
```

Please help me on displaying the above fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when I made this code work in simple php, I extracted the data by

```
$xapo_json = file_get_contents('xapojson.txt');
$xapo_json_decoded = json_decode($xapo_json);
$from_type = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->from->type;
$transacid = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->id;
$from = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->from->id;
$status = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->status;
$amount = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->amount;
$currency = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->currency;
$to = $xapo_json_decoded->resources[0]->resource->to->destination_id;
$datetime = $xapo_json_decoded->datetime;
```

Then in the routes file i changed

```
return view('transaction', compact('transaction'));
```

to

```
return View::make('transaction')->with('transaction',$transaction);
```

And in view I used this

```
{{ $transaction->resources[0]->resource->from->id }}
```

Voila, It works

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the below code ( am taking div as example you can change it to table or whatever

```
@foreach($transaction->resources as $resource)
@if(is_set($resource->from))
<div>{{$resource->from->type}}</div>
@endif
<div>{{$resource->id}}</div>
@if(is_set($resource->from))
<div>{{$resource->from->id}}</div>
@endif
<div>{{$resource->status}}</div>

<div>{{$resource->amount}}</div>

<div>{{$resource->currency}}</div>

<div>{{$resource->to->destination_id}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: well after trying this I am getting error. `ErrorException in 64a884a3b8243906c26295b5c5674b98d081a606.php line 2:
Undefined property: stdClass::$from (View: /home/yash/website/resources/views/transaction.blade.php)`

Comment: It is because some of the the resources doesnt have "from" in that. you can use a conditional query before displaying those i will update the code segment for the same

Comment: Same applies for others as well as the json response have differential set of values for each resource hope you understand the logic from the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 $transaction = json_decode(file_get_contents('xapojson.txt'), true);
```