# Laravel : How do I parse this json data in view blade?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi i have JSon data like this:

```
[{label":a, "value":{"name":"abc","address"="New York"}}]
```

I've success print json with

```
{!! $mydata !!}
```

but when i try use foreach

```
@foreach($mydata['value'] as $value)
    Member ID: {{ $value['name'] }}   
@endforeach
```

The laravel return

```
ErrorException in Collection.php line 1108: Undefined index:value
```

I've followed this : [Laravel: How do I parse this json data in view blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade)

Anyone can help?

Note: The JSON and Variable is not real mine. I was changed it to make it simple.

EDITED:

added `{{ dd(json_decode($tagihan, true)) }}` and return

[Result after added  {{ dd(json_decode($tagihan, true)) }}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUOBx.png)

EDITED:

This my JSON:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "no_rek_pelanggan" => 11115
    "keadaan_meteran" => 0
    "angka_meteran" => 3000
    "created_at" => "2016-05-28 15:28:17"
    "updated_at" => "2016-05-28 15:28:17"
    "all_pelanggan" => array:7 [▼
      "no_rek" => 11115
      "nama" => "Wicak"
      "alamat" => "Malang"
      "long" => 112.6153447
      "lat" => -7.9528411
      "created_at" => "2016-05-26 00:00:00"
      "updated_at" => "2016-05-26 05:00:00"
    ]
  ]
```

I want to read the value from nama, alamat, long, lat in all_pelanggan. How ca i do that?

Comment: my JSON structure are little bit different with JSON on url i was posted above.

Comment: I would say irrespective of any framework you're using, JSON structure parsing is throughout same. Your json is seems like array of objects structure. So once  you have foreach loop for parsing, you would get index and its value inside loop space. you can use traditional for loop or framework specific. Generally I prefer /* for( var index in Array) {} */  because it saves lot of time of execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use json encoded data in a view, use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in `foreach`:

```
@foreach(json_decode($mydata, true) as $value)
    Member ID: {{ $value['all_pelanggan']['name'] }}   
@endforeach
```

Comment: Returned : `Undefined index: all_pelanggan`

Comment: I guess this error is caused by some other code. I don't see `all_pelanggan` in your data. You can see what `json_decode($mydata, true)['value']` generates with `dd(json_decode($mydata, true)['value'])`;

Comment: i mean returned `Undefined index: value`

Comment: Please put this `{{ dd(json_decode($mydata, true)) }}` before `@foreach` part and show me result of it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see what `all_pelanggan` array has in it (it's folded on your screenshot), but I guess it has `name` in it. So I've updated the code, please try `json_decode($mydata, true) as $value` and `$value['all_pelanggan']['name']`.

Comment: Yes! You did it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You didn't followed the question you provided. As stated there you should decode your json in the controller:

```
return view('your-view')->with('mydata', json_decode($mydata, true));
```

Comment: added to my controller, now return this :

`ErrorException in b7982ee647563d1a79c233566311ac51cbab5658.php line 1: Array to string conversion (View: E:\INSTALL\xampp2\htdocs\sipetan\WebService\resources\views\tagihan\index.blade.php)`

Comment: Hai matei, can i ask you one more question? If i have json like this : 

`array:7 [▼
  "id" => 8
  "no_rek_pelanggan" => 11115
  "keadaan_meteran" => 0
  "angka_meteran" => 3000
  "created_at" => "2016-05-28 15:28:17"
  "updated_at" => "2016-05-28 15:28:17"
  "all_pelanggan" => array:7 [▼
    "no_rek" => 11115
    "nama" => "Wicak"
    "alamat" => "Malang"
    "long" => 112.6153447
    "lat" => -7.9528411
    "created_at" => "2016-05-26 00:00:00"
    "updated_at" => "2016-05-26 05:00:00"
  ]
]'`

How can i parse all_pelanggan->nama? I tried same method, but error returned.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an JSON array. But you are trying to fetch JSON object.
If you are sure there is only one object, then use in your controller `Model::<selection-criteria>->first();` so that it will return a JSON object. then "your foreach" will come to work.

If you are not sure there is only one object or in future it will have more objects, then leave your selection statement as it is(It has `->get()` at the end). So it will return an array.

Now modify your foreach to fetch that array. That is your data set is an array and each element is JSON object with sub objects.

```
@foreach($mydata as $myDatum)
    @foreach($myDatum as $val)
        Object label: {{ $val['label'] }}
        Member Name: {{ $val['value']->name }}
        Member Address: {{ $val['value']->address }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($myData); $i++)
   Member ID: {{ $myData[i]['value'] }}
@endfor
```

I hope that works.

Comment: This will print `{"name":"abc","address"="New York"}`. You should get the specific value by calling each object. See my answer.