# Display laravel variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

when i try dd($conv) the data are there, but I still can't display them inside the script. 
Anyone know whats the problem, I have tried many ways but they doesn't seem to work.

```
  <h4>{{$row->transcript_text}}</h4>
    <?php $conv = json_encode($row->transcript_text); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function splitArray() {
            var myStr = <?php echo $conv; ?>;
            var strArray = myStr.split(/(?= \| \d)/);

            // Display array values on page
            for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
                $("body").addClass('col-lg-offset-1').append("<h4>" + strArray[i] + "</h4>");
            })
        }
        splitArray();
    </script>
```

Comment: does it give any error in the console ? If not, what's the generated HTML ?

Comment: Thanks for asking ValLeNain,
No error no data, I just got the blank page. If I do it another way I can display the data (meaning they are there) but I need to split those therefore I have to go this way.

Comment: no error, no data ? And you're sure `$history` is defined, not empty and iterable ?

Comment: yes, because I can display them outside the script

Comment: if you keep the `@foreach` loop but only do `<?php echo json_encode($row->transcript_text);?>`, it works ? Can we see what's generated so ?

Comment: No it doesnt the loop is fine the problem is only in this row: 
var myStr = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($row- >transcript_text);?>); 
the representation of data

Comment: using both templating and pure php in your HTML looks weird to me. Are you sure you have access to `json_encode` in the template ? See this post to render variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30073428/3410584

Comment: What do you mean access to json_encode in the template ?

Comment: Please give us a sample content for your `$history` so we can test your code.

Comment: This code ends up with multiple bodies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Laravel you're using but the recommended way to embed plain PHP in your HTML templates is with the `@php` notation (cf [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#php)).
Anyway, that's something I'd try to avoid. Instead, Laravel blade has native ways of doing what you're trying to do.

```
@if(! empty($history))
    @foreach($history as $row)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function splitArray() {
            var myStr = JSON.parse("{{json_encode($row->transcript_text) }}");
            var strArray = myStr.split(" | 0");

            // Display array values on page
            for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
                $("body").addClass('col-lg-offset-1').append("<h4>" + strArray[i] + "</h4>");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="splitArray()" style="color: lime">
    </body>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2 but this solution does not work, still getting just en emptu page