# JSON response in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I am accessing an API and I get a JSON response from this API:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 455968,
            "name": "Nike Satire",
            "shortName": "Nike Satire",
            "priceMin": 199.99,
            "priceMax": 199.99,
            "discount": 0,
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-satire_600x600-PU6f520_1.jpg",
                "height": 600,
                "width": 600,
                "otherFormats": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-satire_100x100-PU6f520_1.jpg",
                        "height": 100,
                        "width": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-satire_200x200-PU6f520_1.jpg",
                        "height": 200,
                        "width": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-satire_300x300-PU6f520_1.jpg",
                        "height": 300,
                        "width": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-satire_600x600-PU6f520_1.jpg",
                        "height": 600,
                        "width": 600
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hasOffer": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 611192,
            "name": "Nike Air Vapor Ace",
            "shortName": "Nike Air Vapor Ace",
            "priceMin": 229.99,
            "priceMax": 229.99,
            "discount": 0,
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-air-vapor-ace_600x600-PU95378_1.jpg",
                "height": 600,
                "width": 600,
                "otherFormats": [
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-air-vapor-ace_100x100-PU95378_1.jpg",
                        "height": 100,
                        "width": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-air-vapor-ace_200x200-PU95378_1.jpg",
                        "height": 200,
                        "width": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-air-vapor-ace_300x300-PU95378_1.jpg",
                        "height": 300,
                        "width": 300
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https://thumbs.buscape.com.br/tenis/nike-air-vapor-ace_600x600-PU95378_1.jpg",
                        "height": 600,
                        "width": 600
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hasOffer": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

And in the view I am trying to display this information as:

```
    <div class="container container-margin">
        <div class="list-group">
            @foreach($produtos->products as $t)
            <a href="{{ $t->id }}" class="list-group-item"><img src="">{{ $t->name }} - from {{ money_format('%n',$t->priceMin) }} to {{ money_format('%n',$t->priceMax) }}</a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is: How can I display the thumbnail url?

I tried the following approaches:

{{ $t->thumbnail->url }}

{{ $t['thumbnail']['url'] }}

@foreach($t->thumbnail as $v) {{ $v->url }} @endforeach

Nothing seems to work when trying to get a child of a child.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($t)` and check what it actually contains. And like the previous comment, give us more info on what _actually_ happens..

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$url; Cannot use object of type stdClass as array; Trying to get property of non-object. This are the errors that I get.

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert json data to array and then use it as you need.
Take a look for more details here:

[Laravel: How do I parse this json data in view blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade)