# Add fields in laravel dynamically and unlimited

Tags: php, laravel

I have part of my website where users or admins can add restaurant list (is really like posts, just different naming)

There is some fixed inputs such as (title, description and map) I also need a part where users/admins can add restaurants menu this options is obviously can be different for each restaurant as their menu is a short list or long list.

So what I need is like + button where people can add fields and named their menu items with another field for the price of each item.

So my question is how to achieve this option?

What do I have at the moment?

**Restaurant migrate:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRestaurantsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('menu')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->integer('worktimes_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('workday_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('verified')->default(0);
            $table->string('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('restaurants', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('worktimes_id')->references('id')->on('worktimes');
            $table->foreign('workday_id')->references('id')->on('workdays');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('restaurants');
    }
}
```

That's all, I still didn't create CRUD controller for restaurant because I'm holding for this option and your opinions.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

STORE METHOD:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
          'slug' =>'required|max:255',
          'image' =>'sometimes|image',
          'description' => 'required|max:100000',
          'address' => 'sometimes|max:500',
          'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
          'verified' => 'sometimes',
          'status' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

      $restaurant = new Restaurant;

      $restaurant->title = $request->input('title');
      $restaurant->slug = $request->input('slug');
      $restaurant->description = $request->input('description');
      $restaurant->address = $request->input('address');
      $restaurant->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
      $restaurant->verified = $request->input('verified');
      $restaurant->status = $request->input('status');



      if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'restaurant' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);


        $restaurant->image = $filename;
      }


      // menu
      $newArray = array();
      $menuArray = $request->custom_menu; //Contains an array of Menu Values
      $priceArray = $request->custom_price;   //Contains an array of Price Values

      //Creating new array with ARRAY KEY : MENU VALUES and ARRAY VALUE: PRICE VALUES
      foreach ($menuArray as $key => $singleMenu) {
          $newArray[$singleMenu] = $priceArray[$key];
      }
      //Output : array("Menu01" => "Price01", "Menu02" => "Price 02", "Menu03" => "Price 04", "Menu04" => "Price 05")

      //Converting array to json format to store in your table row 'custom_menu_price'
      $jsonFormatData = json_encode($newArray);
      //Output like: {"Menu01":"Price01","Menu02":"Price 02","Menu03":"Price 04","Menu04":"Price 05"}

      // Save in DB
      //
      //
      //

      // To retrieve back from DB to MENU and PRICE values as ARRAY
      $CustomArray = json_decode($jsonFormatData, TRUE);
      foreach ($CustomArray as $menu => $price) {
          echo "Menu:".$menu."<br>";
          echo "Price:".$price."<br>";
      }
      // menu


      $restaurant->save();

      $restaurant->workdays()->sync($request->workdays, false);
      $restaurant->worktimes()->sync($request->worktimes, false);

      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Restaurant, '. $restaurant->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('restaurants.index');
```

Comment: you can store menu as a json in database so each restaurant can have their own json object with different food options even you can store html properties in there

Comment: @AnarBayramov I have no idea how to do that! would you please helping me with giving me a sample?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: hi there , is this is something you want to achieve ? if no please tell me the details more precisely .. https://embed.plnkr.co/HQOuNvDfDwkR2uLD632u/

Comment: @demonyowh hi bro, that's exactly what i need for my form + now I'm using sreejith bs codes for storing data which is works but also save additional empty input.  So now i need these: stop that additional empty input to be save and use your method in my form. Please see my comments on sreejith answer to see what i mean of additional empty input.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is

1) add another one table row for `custom_menu_price` in your migration file

```
$table->string('custom_menu_price')->nullable();
```

2) Modify your `form`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ ...... }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    //I'm Looping the input fields 5 times here
    @for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
        Enter Menu {{ $i }} : <input type="text" name="custom_menu[]">  //**Assign name as ARRAY
        Enter Price {{ $i }} : <input type="text" name="custom_price[]">  //**Assign name as ARRAY
        <br><br>
    @endfor

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

3) In your `controller`

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    //Validating title and body field
    $this->validate($request, array(
      'title'=>'required|max:225',
      'slug' =>'required|max:255',
      'image' =>'sometimes|image',
      'description' => 'required|max:100000',
      'address' => 'sometimes|max:500',
      'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
      'verified' => 'sometimes',
      'status' => 'required|numeric',
    ));

    $restaurant = new Restaurant;

    $restaurant->title = $request->input('title');
    $restaurant->slug = $request->input('slug');
    $restaurant->description = $request->input('description');
    $restaurant->address = $request->input('address');
    $restaurant->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $restaurant->verified = $request->input('verified');
    $restaurant->status = $request->input('status');

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = 'restaurant' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);
        $restaurant->image = $filename;
    }

    // menu
    $newArray = array();
    $menuArray = $request->custom_menu; //Contains an array of Menu Values
    $priceArray = $request->custom_price;   //Contains an array of Price Values

    //Creating new array with ARRAY KEY : MENU VALUES and ARRAY VALUE: PRICE VALUES
    foreach ($menuArray as $key => $singleMenu) {
      $newArray[$singleMenu] = $priceArray[$key];
    }
    //Output : array("Menu01" => "Price01", "Menu02" => "Price 02", "Menu03" => "Price 04", "Menu04" => "Price 05")

    //Converting array to json format to store in your table row 'custom_menu_price'
    $jsonFormatData = json_encode($newArray);
    //Output like: {"Menu01":"Price01","Menu02":"Price 02","Menu03":"Price 04","Menu04":"Price 05"}

    // Save in DB
    $restaurant->custom_menu_price = $jsonFormatData;
    // menu

    $restaurant->save();

    $restaurant->workdays()->sync($request->workdays, false);
    $restaurant->worktimes()->sync($request->worktimes, false);

    //Display a successful message upon save
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Restaurant, '. $restaurant->title.' created');
    return redirect()->route('restaurants.index');
}
```

inside your `front.restaurantshow` view:

```
@php
    // To retrieve back from DB to MENU and PRICE values as ARRAY
    $CustomArray = json_decode($restaurant->custom_menu_price, TRUE);
@endphp

@foreach ($CustomArray as $menu => $price)
    Menu Name: {{ $menu }} <br>
    Menu Price: {{ $price }} <br><br>
@endforeach
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: this part `// Save in DB` i assume i must make new table with row's of `menu` and `price` right?

Comment: Not needed. Just save that json in one table column, say custom_menu_price

Comment: That way you could retrieve easily from DB as KEY PAIR values later.

Comment: i did all those, i've got no error on store methode, now please tell me how to see where that json file saved, and how to show it in front-end? i'm total 0 in this :)

Comment: Have you added extra row in migration?

Comment: I changed my `menu` column to `custom_menu_price`

Comment: Modified my answer.

Comment: now is working, but my output is like this `{"ARGQEH":"324235235","SAFGARG":"324325","":null} `

Comment: Yes. its json format. Use json_decode to get back as MENU and Price seperately. Updated the code.

Comment: so how to make it fix?

Comment: What is the error to fix? Understand more about json encode and decode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade

Comment: no error i just want to show items as a list and not like `{"ARGQEH":"324235235","SAFGARG":"324325","":null}` i want show them as table with their price.

Comment: can you believe if i say i've got actual headache? where should i add this `json_decode()` you added?

Comment: Inside methods for listing restauarants, you need menu and price seperate. Thats where you would do json_decode to get actual data back.

Comment: if i add it to my show method i will get error of `Undefined variable: jsonFormatData`

Comment: this is my show method   ->      public function restaurantsshow($slug) {
      $restaurant = Restaurant::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
      return view('front.restaurantshow', compact('restaurant'));
    }

Comment: Because when you saved them as json in DB , there might be null. You may have omitted filling any MENU or PRICE when you submitted the form.

Comment: i just fulfilled 3 rows and the rest 2 i did not.

Comment: Give some condition to check if its null before saving to DB as json.

Comment: hmmmmm :-D if i knew how to work with that json thing why would i ask here :-p