# display ckeditor data saved in database in div tag

Tags: php, html, laravel, ckeditor

> i want to display ckeditor data saved in dadabase in div tag. I mean,
>   I save ckeditor data to the database and restore this data to the
>   div tag and also with the tags being applied to that text.
>
> When typing this code, the following text will be displayed

this is code:

```
<div> {{$object->text}} </div>
```

> It displays this;
>   I want these tags to apply

```
html> <head> <title></title> </head> <body dir="rtl"> <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{!! $object->text !!}
```

string will auto escape when you'll use {{ }}

Comment: Accept the answer so that this post/answer can be helpful for others as well :)

Comment: Is there a similar way to json?

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/