# How do I parse this json inside array data in view blade?

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle, laravel-blade

Currently this is my view

```
        {{ $data["id_user"] }}
```

my controller

```
$client = new Client;
    $request = $client->get('url')->getBody()->getContents();  
    return view('Admin/lala')->with('data', json_decode($request, true));
```

get api

```
    {
  "code": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id_user": 1      
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to display it, I've tried it like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade) but it's still an error.
is there something wrong when I parse the data

Comment: can you post your blade file?

Comment: okay so the data in your json is an array so you need to use foreach.
{{  $data['code'] }} it will work and for data in json use foreach($data['data'] as $json_d){
 {{ $json_d['id_user'] }}
}

Comment: do a dd($request); and show me the response how it looks

Comment: my dd respon @LeoinstanceofKelmendi
"{"code":200,"data":[{"id_user":1 ▶"

Comment: blade file results @pseudoanime
"Undefined index: id_user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your json your **id_user** is inside array **data** so you have to use foreach in your blade.

Controller:

```
$client = new Client;
$request = $client->get('url')->getBody()->getContents();  
return view('Admin/lala')->with('data', json_decode($request, true));
```

you can also do it like this:

```
$client = new Client;
$request = $client->get('url')->getBody()->getContents();  
$data = json_decode($request, true);
return view('Admin/lala', compact('data'));
```

in your Blade file:

```
 // since it is not an array so you access code with out using foreach
 {{ $data['code'] }}

 //since id_user is in array so using foreach 
 @foreach($data['data'] as $json_d)

  {{ $json_d['id_user'] }}

 @endforeach
```