# how to display json data into laravel blade?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-blade

```
public function bar()
{

    $lowm = new LaravelOWM();
    $for = $lowm->getWeatherForecast('lahore');
     $ff= json_decode(json_encode($for),true);
    dd($for);
}
```

this is the output its I think multi-dimensional array and I just want to print only few things. Tell me the answer through for each loop.

```
array:3 [▼
  "city" => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1172451
    "name" => "Lahore"
    "country" => "PK"
    "population" => null
    "lat" => 31.5196
    "lon" => 74.3263
  ]
  "sun" => array:2 [▼
    "rise" => array:3 [▼
      "date" => "2018-09-17 00:48:17.000000"
      "timezone_type" => 3
      "timezone" => "UTC"
    ]
    "set" => array:3 [▼
      "date" => "2018-09-17 13:05:08.000000"
      "timezone_type" => 3
      "timezone" => "UTC"
    ]
  ]
  "lastUpdate" => array:3 [▼
    "date" => "2018-09-17 23:00:29.303267"
    "timezone_type" => 3
    "timezone" => "UTC"
  ]
]
```

I just want to display city name, lat and lon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765162/how-do-i-parse-this-json-inside-array-data-in-view-blade/51766585#51766585

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
public function bar() {
    $lowm = new LaravelOWM();
    $for = $lowm->getWeatherForecast('lahore');
    dump('City: '. $for->city->name);
    dump('Latitude: '. $for->city->lat);
    dump('Longitude: '. $for->city->lon);
}
```

[More Here](https://github.com/cmfcmf/OpenWeatherMap-PHP-Api/blob/master/Examples/WeatherForecast.php)