# Displaying JSON-collection in Blade

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display JSON data from my Database, using Laravel and Blade.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Open Projects",
        "sequence": "1",
        "columns": [
            "Open Projects",
            "Owner"
        ],
        "col": {
            "index": "1",
            "value": "title",
            "type": "longtext",
            "heading": "1"
        },
        "0": {
            "title": "Owner",
            "index": "2",
            "value": "owner",
            "type": "longtext",
            "heading": "0"
        }
    },
    ... more
]
```

When I try to print one of the collections, I get the error:
`"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: ...)"`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My Json format data i displayed in question.I need to display this in my blade view using laravel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: How do I parse this json data in view blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade)

Comment: My question is different.Inside the JSOn data i have aray with  name 'columns.But i give  like  columns : {{ $value['columns'] }}, am getting error  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, ..

Comment: First, welcome to Stack Overflow. :-) Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to show us that in your question - we have no idea what you want or what your problem is. Please add what you have tried so far, which error you're seeing, what you expect to see, etc - without adding hundreds of lines of code. Small and concrete. :-)

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is not in the code sample you have provided. Please ensure that you are showing a verifiable example and ask a relevant question. Also, being rude to members is never OK.

Answer (score 0):

`"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` happens when you try to print an array using `{{ $variable }}`. Instead, you will need to convert it to a string or loop over it. The solution below loops over your collections.

Assuming that you inject your JSON like this:

```
return view('myview', ["json" => json_decode($json, true)]);
```

You can print your values like this:

```
@foreach($json as $project)
    <p>Title: {{ $project["title"] }}</p>
    <p>Sequence: {{ $project["sequence"] }}</p>
    <p>Columns: </p>
    <ul>
        @foreach($project["col"] as $key => $value)
            <li>{{ $key }} : {{ $value }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <p>"0" <- whatever this is</p>
    <ul>
        @foreach($project["0"] as $key => $value)
            <li>{{ $key }} : {{ $value }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```