# How to Print json values in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I Send data in db json formate in this create function.

```
public function create(Request $request)
  {

    $posts = new Post();
    $posts->user_id = $request->id;
    $posts->title = $request->title;
    $posts->description = $request->description;
    $tags = explode(",", $request->labels);
    $encode = json_encode($tags);
    $posts->tags = $encode;
    $posts->save();
      return redirect()->back()->with('message' , 'post created!!!!!');

  }
```

In this getdata function fetch data from db

```
 public function getdata()
  {
      $posts = Post::all();
      return view('allposts',compact('posts'));
  }
```

now i print data in blade file but tags value is null in tag field.
How to print json values??

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<tr>
    <td>{{$post->title}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->description}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->tags}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{url('edit_post',$post->id)}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">update</button></a>
        <a href="{{route('delete_post',$post->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >delete</button></a>
    </td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Perhaps looking at this post can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade

Comment: It's not related to json format, can you check database tags has any value? it should have something like {"value": "value"}, if it is null, it print null.