# How shall I use PHP yield method

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8, yield

I'm trying to write an api controller that pulls the user's statistics with php, but this controller I wrote works very slowly. Based on my other programming language experiences, I decided to try the yield method, but an error appears, what is the reason and what should I do? Thanks in advance.

**this is controller code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class splenperAPIController extends Controller
{
    public function splenperAPI()
    {

        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'cookie' => 'sessionid=1796659686%3A4Ojj1py72bZKql%3A7;csrftoken=fPYrPRD1vHB7LdS0DjKzOK4kGo4uYK9f;',
            'x-ig-app-id' => '936619743392459',
        ])->get('https://www.instagram.com/elmaligroup/?__a=1');

        $response = $response->json();
        $userId = $response['graphql']['user']['id'];

        $first = 12;
        $variables = json_encode([
            'id' => $userId,
            "first" => $first,
        ]);

        $variables = urlencode($variables);
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'cookie' => 'sessionid=1796659686%3A4Ojj1py72bZKql%3A7; csrftoken=fPYrPRD1vHB7LdS0DjKzOK4kGo4uYK9f; ds_user_id=1796659686; ig_did=25114CCD-7A9D-4971-88F1-1E04796D9F14; ig_nrcb=1; mid=YiqZZQALAAEhkff6N5T2oovGOBkz; rur=01f73b7ee19feca3df296fc45ee75179c49dd54efb93233307b58f19bf707fea5d458fe7; shbid=01f7998eadf528233f0e7331b327e5a107134084c64e229af2cc6577b8a2ce862e3798da; shbts=01f7caf607a6877ca8407e9cb85cd175736a87f8f75e9076d5bddb32cbcbac6d5da45e89',
            'x-ig-app-id' => '936619743392459',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->get('https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=e769aa130647d2354c40ea6a439bfc08&variables=' . $variables);

        $mediaCount = $response->json()['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count'];
        $totalLikeCount = 0;
        $totalCommentCount = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $mediaCount; $i++) {
           yield $totalCommentCount += $response->json()['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][$i]['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count'];
           yield $totalLikeCount += $response->json()['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][$i]['node']['edge_media_preview_like']['count'];
           yield $userName = $response->json()['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][$i]['node']['owner']['username'];
        }

        echo "userId:" . $userId . '<br>';
        echo "totalLikeCount:" . $totalLikeCount . '<br>';
        echo "totalCommentCount:" . $totalCommentCount . '<br>';
        echo "userName:" . $userName . '<br>';
        echo "mediaCount:" . $mediaCount;
    }
}
```

**this is error code**

```
TypeError
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Generator given, called in C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\splenperAPI\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72
```

Comment: I would recommend returning a JSON from the API. Using yield method in a function causes the function return a generator that is an iterable object. Such object is not expected when Symphony/Laravel is building a response generated by a Controller.

Comment: the api is already json so what can i do this*

Comment: I meant returning JSON from your splenperAPI controller.

Comment: OK, so you want to keep it as a json object instead of reflecting it on the screen with echo. It's nice, but we need to display this data in a blade structure, if we do it, will the same things happen?

Comment: regarding JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade
Regarding YIELD (it is not what you need): https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php