# read object of object data laravel blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-blade

data looks like this

```
[
    {
      "id": 22528,
      "user_id": 25273,
      "non_sql": "{\"data\": {\"data_1\": \"4\", \"data_2\": \"5\", \"data_3\": \"4\", \"data_4\": \"5\"}}",
      "created_at": "2022-06-12T04:38:36.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-06-12T04:40:10.000000Z",
    },
]
```

when tried

```
 <td>{{ $item["non_sql"] ??  'NA' }}</td>
```

it gives me

```
{"data": {"data_1": "4", "data_2": "5", "data_3": "4", "data_4": "5"}}
```

I just need to return

```
data_1: 4
data_2: 5
data_3: 4
data_4: 5
```

I tried

```
<td>{{ json_decode($item["non_sql"]) ??  'NA' }}</td>
```

and have error htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, stdClass given

Comment: @Refilon give me this error Cannot access offset of type string on string

Comment: Your `non_sql` contains a JSON string, so you will need to decode that first.

Comment: Why are you having the same isset check there twice? That makes little sense to begin with - it will never reach the "branch" after the `:`, if it _was_ set; and if it wasn't ... well then the second isset won't get a different result all of a sudden either.

Comment: @CBroe i tried <td>{{ jsone_decode($item["non_sql"]) ??  'NA' }}</td> and have this error Call to undefined function jsone_decode()

Comment: Well then spell it correctly, and leave out the extra `e`...

Comment: @CBroe oh sorry, but now have this htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, stdClass given

Comment: The content of `non_sql`, when decoded, is an object - so it makes little sense to try and output that directly in a context, where a string value is expected. You need to access individual properties of the object.

Comment: @CBroe so I need two json_decode?

Comment: No, you only have one level of JSON encoding at this point.

Comment: @CBroe so you mean access by foreach?

Comment: Give us the code where you send that item to view

Comment: @angel.bonev I read it from json file  return view(
            'gameResult.game-result-table',
            [
                'result' => $result,
                'game'   => $game,
                'sort_by' => $sort_by,
            ]
        );   then use foreach result as item

Comment: @RaneemAyman where ? Give us that code

Comment: @angel.bonev result is my json file in controller

Comment: add `foreach ($result as $k => $v) { $result[$k]["non_sql"] = json_decode($v["non_sql"], true);}` before the return and try `{{$item["non_sql"]["data"]["data_1"]}}`

Comment: @RaneemAyman is it showing something ?

Comment: @angel.bonev do this in blade?

Comment: No in the controller in laravel before the view

Comment: @angel.bonev "Undefined array key "data" and when try {{$item["non_sql"]["data"]}} it give me same error tmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Comment: `{{$item["non_sql"]["data"]}}` it is an array try `{{$item["non_sql"]["data"]["data_1"]}}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: How do I parse this json data in view blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073065/laravel-how-do-i-parse-this-json-data-in-view-blade)

Comment: @angel.bonev I don't know if this will help but non_sql in resul file looks like this "non_sql": "{\"data\": {\"data_1\": \"4\", \"data_2\": \"5\", \"data_3\": \"4\"} it is object

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

{{ implode(",",json_decode($item["non_sql"])) ??  'NA' }}

Comment: give me this error implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, stdClass given

Comment: when i update the code like this it works but this only prints the value values.; 
implode(',',json_decode($data['non_sql'],true)['data'])  \n you can print regularly with loop management